# How to use counter in xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium, rc

I am using the following code to get the id of a row that is randomly generated:

```
string[] rowIds = new string[numofRowsPassengerTable];
for (int counter=1; counter < numofRowsPassengerTable; counter++)
{
    rowIds[counter] = browser.GetAttribute("xpath=//table[@id='tblPassengers']/tbody/tr[counter]@id");
}
```

But the above is not returning anything. If I use `1` or `2` instead of `counter` it returns the id. Any idea how can I use that counter to get row ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you wanted to actually use "counter" as a variable in the xpath string:

```
browser.GetAttribute("xpath=//table[@id='tblPassengers']/tbody/tr[" + counter + "]@id");
```

As it stands now, you tell the XPath engine to use some "counter" HTML element as index to the TRs, which obviously won't work.